# Developing two different algorithms for finding a certain element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am currently practicing algorithm development with Java and have recently really got stuck on a particular problem. I have been challenged to develop two different algorithm.

My task is to solve the selection problem. the selection problem determines the kth largest number in a group of N numbers.

I have successfully implemented the first algorithm. I read the N numbers into an array, sort the array in decreasing order by some simple algorithm, and then return the element in position k.

**Note: k = N / 2**

**Here is the working code**

```
public int selectionAlgorithmOne() {

    int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10};

    //I sort the array of size N in decreasing order 
    bubbleSortDecreasingOrder(intArray);
    //{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

    //I obtain the value of k
    int k = intArray.length / 2;

    //I print the result
    System.out.println(intArray[k]);
}
```

The value that is printed in "**5**" which is correct! However, the second algorithm is a bit trickier.

Read the first k elements into an array and sort them in decreasing order. Next, each remaining element is read one by one. As a new element arrives, it is ignored if it is smaller than the kth element in the array. Otherwise, it is placed in its correct spot in the array, bumping one element out of the array. When the algorithm ends, the element in the kth position is returned as the answer.

Unfortunately my second algorithm does not work. It returns the value "**3**" which is wrong. It should be returning the same value of "**5**" as the first algorithm but in a more efficient.

I have been stuck for a few days now and I am really struggling to find the solution. Hopefully I have given the problem enough context, let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the non-working code**

```
public int selectionAlgorithmTwo() {

    int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10};

    int arrayLength = intArray.length;
    int k = arrayLength / 2;
    int[] firstHalf = new int[k];

    //I read the first half of the elements into an array
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        firstHalf[i] = intArray[i];
    }

    //I then sort the first half of the elements in decreasing order
    bubbleSort(firstHalf);

    for(int i = k; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        int val = intArray[i];

    //If the new element to insert is >= the kth largest
        if (val > firstHalf[k - 1]) {
            int pos = 0;
            for(; pos < k; pos++) {
                if(val > firstHalf[pos]) {
                    break; //I break once I have the correct position located
                }
    //I make the swap
                for (int j = k - 1; j > pos; j--)
                    firstHalf[j] = firstHalf[j - 1];
                firstHalf[pos] = val;
            }
        }
    }
    return firstHalf[k - 1];
}
```

Comment: Just a quickshot, I feel this `if(val > firstHalf[pos])` should be `if(val < firstHalf[pos])`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately the algorithm returns the value 10 and not 5 as expected.

Comment: Please show the content of both arrays at the end of the function and at the time when the firsrt half has just been filled and sorted.

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve], with additional information on the state of the arrays in critical situations.

Comment: I don’t think that second for loop should be nested within the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "the element in position k" isn't the kth element, it's the k+1 th element. Indeed **5** is the sixth element of the sorted array.
So, if you want to return the element in position k, you need an array of k+1 element.
Therefore I added the `firstHalfLen` variable.
If you use an array of k element, you'll never get **5** as answer.

In the block `if (val > firstHalf[k])`, in order to find the correct index, I preferred a while loop

```
while ((pos < firstHalfLen) && (val <= firstHalf[pos])) {
    pos++;
}
```

Then the swap:

```
for (int j = k; j > pos; j--) {
    firstHalf[j] = firstHalf[j - 1];
}
```

Code:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] { 1, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10 };

int arrayLength = intArray.length;
int k = arrayLength / 2;
int firstHalfLen = k + 1;
int[] firstHalf = new int[firstHalfLen];

// I read the first half of the elements into an array
for (int i = 0; i < firstHalfLen; i++) {
    firstHalf[i] = intArray[i];
}

//I then sort the first half of the elements in decreasing order
bubbleSort(firstHalf);

for (int i = firstHalfLen; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    int val = intArray[i];

    // If the new element to insert is >= the kth largest
    if (val > firstHalf[k]) {
        int pos = 0;
        // find index
        while ((pos < firstHalfLen) && (val <= firstHalf[pos])) {
            pos++;
        }

        // Swap
        for (int j = k; j > pos; j--) {
            firstHalf[j] = firstHalf[j - 1];
        }
        firstHalf[pos] = val;

    }
}

return firstHalf[k];
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing values from the unsorted part to values of the sorted part, starting low, i.e. at small values. The probability that the value is larger than the first sorted value is quite high. More interesting would be a value which is smaller. According to your algorithm, the smaller unsorted value should be inserted into the small sorted values, at the position where it replaces a higher value, not a smaller one.

So

```
if(val > firstHalf[pos])
```

should be

```
if(val < firstHalf[pos])
```

Comment: Upon making that change, I added a print statement to print the "firstHalf". At the end of the algorithm, firstHalf contains the values [10,10,10,10,10].

Comment: Please show the content of **both** arrays at the end of the function **and** at the time when the first half has just been filled and sorted. Do so in the question, not in a comment on an answer, in order to have more space and more helpful formatting available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public int sortTest() {
    int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 7, 9, 8, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 10};

    int arrayLength = intArray.length;
    int k = arrayLength / 2;
    int[] firstHalf = new int[k];

    //I read the first half of the elements into an array
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        firstHalf[i] = intArray[i];
    }

    //I then sort the first half of the elements in decreasing order
    bubbleSort(firstHalf);

    for(int i = k; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        int val = intArray[i];

        //If the new element to insert is >= the kth largest
        if (val > firstHalf[k - 1]) {
            int pos = 0;
            for(; pos < k; pos++) {
                if(val > firstHalf[pos]) {
                    break; //I break once I have the correct position located
                }
            }
            //I make the swap
            for (int j = k - 1; j > pos; j--)
                firstHalf[j] = firstHalf[j - 1];
            firstHalf[pos] = val;

        }
    }
    return firstHalf[k - 1];
}
```

The error in your code is that, after you found the correct position and break, you leave the for loop without the swap procedure.

Also note that this code return 6, not 5, because you returned the k-1 th value.